# Unresolved function .map in ionic 2 RC0 project

Tags: ionic2

I am getting an 'unresolved function' error for a .map in an ionic 2 RC0 project.

The code looks like this:

```js
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Events} from 'ionic-angular';
import {Http, RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';
import {API_ENDPOINT} from '../app_settings';
import {DjangoAuth} from '../providers/djangoAuth';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Injectable()
export class ImageData {

  userID:number  = 0;
  data:any;
  httpBody:any;

  constructor(public http: Http, public events: Events, public djangoAuth: DjangoAuth) {

  }


  loadImages(theUserID, numberItemsToGet, feedType){
    var additional_parameters = '';
    var theCategoriesWanted = 'ALL';

    if (feedType == 'USERS'){
      additional_parameters = '&fromthisuser=true';
      theCategoriesWanted = 'ALL';
    }
    else if (feedType == 'UNSEEN'){
      additional_parameters = '';
    }
    else if (feedType == 'BOOKMARKS'){
      additional_parameters = '&bookmarked=True'+this.userID;
      theCategoriesWanted = 'ALL';
    }

    return this.djangoAuth.createHeaders(true).then((headers) => {
      var options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers, withCredentials: this.djangoAuth.use_session});

      return new Promise(resolve => {
        this.http.get(API_ENDPOINT + 'items/?categories=' + theCategoriesWanted + '&num=' + numberItemsToGet + '&user=' + this.userID + '&format=json' + additional_parameters, options)
          .map(res => res.json())
          .subscribe(
            (data: any) => {
              this.data = data;
              resolve(this.data);
            },
            (err: any) => {
              resolve("api/items returned error: " + err);
            },
            () => {
              //alert('Complete');
            }
          );
      });
    });
  }
```

This code used to work before I updated to ionic 2 RC0.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your IDE to use Typescript 2.0.3 and ECMAScript6

This worked for me.

Comment: My IDE is up to date but I am still getting the same problem.